# How to responsively scale element in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make an animated element resize responsively, like using VW.
But I think it's impossible to do without ruining the animation.
Help me with this please, guys.

HTML:

```
<div class="slidebar" id="slide" >
        <div class="hamburger" id="hamburger-1" onclick="hamburger()">
          <span class="line"></span>
          <span class="line"></span>
          <span class="line"></span>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slidebar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 17px;
    right: 25px;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger .line{
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    margin: 8px auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    
}
#hamburger-1.is-active .line:nth-child(2){
    opacity: 0;
  }
.hamburger:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
  
#hamburger-1.is-active .line:nth-child(2){
    opacity: 0;
}
  
#hamburger-1.is-active .line:nth-child(1){
    -webkit-transform: translateY(13px) rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: translateY(13px) rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: translateY(13px) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translateY(13px) rotate(45deg);
}
#hamburger-1.is-active .line:nth-child(3){
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-13px) rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-13px) rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: translateY(-13px) rotate(-45deg);
    transform: translateY(-13px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

JS:

```
function hamburger(){
    var hamburg = document.getElementById('hamburger-1');
    hamburg.classList.toggle("is-active");
    var slidebar = document.getElementById("slide");
    slidebar.classList.toggle("is-active");
}
```

I made a JSFiddle as well to make it easier for you all to take a look. Here it is:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ytqdajb/)

Please, only JS, CSS and HTML.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to resize your burger button depending on the screen size, but why don't you want to use media-queries?

Comment: I tried, but i don' think that creating 4 or 5 media-queries for only 1 burger button is good idea. I'm thinking about more complicated and short solution of this problem.

Comment: And VW doesn't work correctly with resizing and animation. If i resize the lines, then all animation ruins.

Comment: please check my solution and let me know about the result

Comment: the lines don't get any thicker, the lines just keep their width, past the overall width of the hamburger. since dynamic resizing only affects the overall width of the hamburger button.

Comment: Yes, they don't change their thickness, or perhaps their height.
But they look like they are thick, and i want to make them thinner.
I tried to change their height, but again, animation ruined.
I will be very thankful if you help me with this problem now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood the question correctly, you need to dynamically change the width of the burger button. try adding the following to the `.hamburger .line` class:

```
width: 10vw;
max-width: 50px;
```

Comment: It kinda works well, but much website resizes down, lines are getting thicker
https://ibb.co/WHjWLcP
https://ibb.co/VV5Xw3n

Answer (score 0):

I would convert all of your `px` values to `em` using this [tool](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_pxtoemconversion.asp). This would make all sizes relative to its parent's `font-size`, (2em means 2 times the size of the parent's font).

*More about CSS units [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units).*

```
.hamburger .line {
    width: 3.125em;
    height: 0.3125em;
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    margin: 0.5em auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#hamburger-1.is-active .line:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
}

.hamburger:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#hamburger-1.is-active .line:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
}

#hamburger-1.is-active .line:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(0.8125em) rotate(45deg);
}

#hamburger-1.is-active .line:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-0.8125em) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Then using media query, I would change the `font-size` of the `.hamburger` accordingly.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .hamburger {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
}

/* more media queries for .hamburger here */
```

If you  wan't you could set `.hamburgers`'s `font-size` using `vw` to avoid media queries.

[image: Edit sleepy-joliot-ycf99]